# How to pass Angular environment variables to Gitlab CI/CD Pipeline

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, environment-variables

```js
# For the testing stage you must include all those lines so the tests run and finish. If  ng test doesnt have the flags that come after it, it will hang on that stage.

image: node:latest

before_script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
    - gem install dpl

stages:
    - production




production:
    type: deploy
    stage: production
    image: ruby:latest
    script:
        - dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_APP_PRODUCTION --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
    only:
        - master
```

Good Evening,
I am trying to use my environment key that is set up in the environment file in Angular in my pipeline, but Gitlab does not know how to use it. process.env.(insert variable name) does not work. I have set the env variable in my gitlab pipeline dashboard. I am just not sure how to use that in my app. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats quite a long answer, you *need to list your config* or job so we can trouble shoot. In short here are the main components to setup

First setup pipeline jobs like so, you should see your image in your dashboard

```
myTestjob:
  stage: stage_a
  image: node:12-alpine
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    - node --version
```

Second, setup your dependencies

```
stages:
  - install

install_dependencies:
  stage: install
  image: node:12-alpine
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    - yarn install
    - yarn ngcc --properties es2015 --create-ivy-entry-points
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        - yarn.lock
    paths:
      - node_modules
  only:
    refs:
      - merge_requests
      - master
    changes:
      - yarn.lock
```

remember that your cache key is invalidated whenever you make changes to yarn.lock

```
cache:
  key:
    files:
      - yarn.lock
  paths:
    - node_modules
  policy: pull
```

In your angular,json build your application job

```
{  
  "projects": {
    "angular-app-example": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "artifacts/app"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Setup your env variable, gitlab has many

```
variables:
  PROJECT_PATH: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR"
  APP_OUTPUT_PATH: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/artifacts/app"

build_app:
  stage: build_and_test
  image: node:12-alpine
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    - yarn ng build --prod
  after_script:
    - cp $PROJECT_PATH/Dockerfile $APP_OUTPUT_PATH
  artifacts:
    name: "angular-app-pipeline"
    paths:
      - $APP_OUTPUT_PATH
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        - yarn.lock
    paths:
      - node_modules
    policy: pull
```

here is a nice [ref.](https://javascript-conference.com/blog/build-test-deployment-angular-gitlab-ci/) on how to setup in more detail

---

**UPDATE** after user posted YML file to setup staging and production

```
cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

deploy_stage:
  stage: deploy
  environment: Stage
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - rm ./package-lock.json
    - npm install
    - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng test --progress false --single-run=true --watch=false
    - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng e2e --progress false --watch=false
    - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --progress false --prod --base-href tykt-stage.surge.sh
    - ./node_modules/.bin/surge -p dist/ --domain tykt-stage.surge.sh

deploy_production:
  stage: deploy
  environment: Production
  only:
    - tags
  script:
    - rm ./package-lock.json
    - npm install
    - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng test --progress false --single-run=true  --watch=false
    - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng e2e --progress false --watch=false
    - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --progress false --prod --base-href tykt.surge.sh
    - ./node_modules/.bin/surge -p dist/ --domain tykt.surge.sh
```

You can use either section and update your domain it should build and push the CI CD

Comment: Please see my above .yml file. I have declared my env variables with gitlab